# Modifying bottom legend in column chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, legend

How to make legend as shown in the picture?

[image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/101350199@N05/14406075674/]

I used text box and shapes to get those but is there a way to get Excel to do it automatically?

Comment: I haven't used VBA before but I can use it if that's the only way. I can google for online resources and learn a bit of VBA and do it. However, can you please outline on how to get the required style using VBA? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say, but I think that is impossible. Excel groups graph legends in a very specific way and I cannot find a way to manipulate each label. Thus, it can't be recorded or coded as a macro in VBA. I would comment, but I don't have the rep points.

I tried using the macro recorder to make text boxes and shapes like you mentioned. Here is what I got. Try modifying this.

```
Sub Macro6()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 338.25, 435, 62.25 _
    , 30.75).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Series 1"
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).ParagraphFormat. _
        FirstLineIndent = 0
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 6).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(7, 2).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 433.5, 464.25, 67.5 _
        , 24).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Series 2"
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).ParagraphFormat. _
        FirstLineIndent = 0
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 6).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(7, 2).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 530.25, 435, 61.5, _
        24).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Series 3"
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).ParagraphFormat. _
        FirstLineIndent = 0
    With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 322.5, 435.75, 13.5, 15).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 416.25, 465, 15, 15.75).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset10
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 513.75, 435, 14.25, 15.75).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset11

End Sub
```